# Extracting params from the Referer Header field in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

I understand that I can use [url_param / urlp](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#urlp) to extract the `query parameters` from the URL that is requested, in HAProxy.

However, I need similar function for extracting parameters from the URL sent as HTTP Header field `Referer`. I guess `url_param` is only available for the requested URL, and not possible to use for HTTP Header values? If so, what other options do I have? I need to retrieve the value from query parameter and send it as specific HTTP Header to the backend server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing my solution (although Im not sure this is the most efficient and accurate way). I solved it with Regex.

```
# Example HTTP Referer: http://myexample.com/users?user-id=12345

# ACL
acl is_uid_in_hdr_referer       hdr_sub(Referer)   -i user-id

# Set value from query param "user-id" from Referer header to custom header "user-id"
http-request set-header         user-id %[req.hdr(Referer),regsub(.+?user-id=,,g)]    if is_uid_in_hdr_referer
```